# Why does this PHP image conversion method create completely transparent images?

Tags: php, webp

I am using the below method to batch convert images to the `.webp` format (borrowed from **[here](https://www.jclabs.co.uk/generate-webp-images-in-php-using-and-gd-or-imagick/)**):

```
public function convertToWebp($file, $compression_quality = 80) {
    // check if file exists
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        return false;
    }

    // If output file already exists return path
    $output_file = $file . '.webp';
    if (file_exists($output_file)) {
        return $output_file;
    }

    $file_type = strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));


    if (function_exists('imagewebp')) {

        switch ($file_type) {
            case 'jpeg':
            case 'jpg':
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                break;

            case 'png':
                $image = imagecreatefrompng($file);
                imagepalettetotruecolor($image);
                imagealphablending($image, true);
                imagesavealpha($image, true);
                break;

            case 'gif':
                $image = imagecreatefromgif($file);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }

        // Save the image
        $result = imagewebp($image, $output_file, $compression_quality);
        if (false === $result) {
            return false;
        }

        // Free up memory
        imagedestroy($image);

        return $output_file;
    } elseif (class_exists('Imagick')) {
        $image = new Imagick();
        $image->readImage($file);

        if ($file_type === 'png') {
            $image->setImageFormat('webp');
            $image->setImageCompressionQuality($compression_quality);
            $image->setOption('webp:lossless', 'true');
        }

        $image->writeImage($output_file);
        return $output_file;
    }

    return false;
}
```

In the view file:

```
foreach ($images as $image) {
  <img class="img-responsive" src="<?= convertToWebp($image);?>"/>
}
```

#### The problem

While most of the images are converted successfully, some are completely transparent.

What is missing?

If the Imagick library does not have support for `.webp` what's a good workaround?

Comment: Which case generates transparent images?  Or is it multiple? And which image lib?

Comment: @Don'tPanic It is multiple.

Comment: have you checked the `src` value? is it actully transparent or is src empty due to `return false`?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone the original (.png) files are all fine.

Comment: I haven't got much experience with the used php functions but from the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php) I can see that Alphablending has to be disabled (imagealphablending($im, false)) to retain the alpha-channel in the first place. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou There is no transparency to preserve. The issue is too much transparency.

Comment: can you provide an image which doesn't work, or make a [replit](https://replit.com/) etc, i.e [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), my guess is the image is not a png, somewhere along the line had its extension changed, presuming you actually checked src="" is not empty